# Reorder to some items and changing primary key

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence, rows

I've a table `MENU_ITEMS` with a column `SEQ` to define the position at which each item should be displayed in a menu.  Simplified for the sake of this question, something like...

```
MENU_ITEMS:
ITEM_CODE    PARENT_CODE   SEQ* (*unique to parent)
------------------------------
BANANAS      FRUIT         1      
APPLES       FRUIT         2 
CHERRIES     FRUIT         4
DURIANS      FRUIT         3
POTATOES     VEG           1
```

I've a procedure to re-order the items.  One of its parameters is a string array containing the `ITEM_CODEs` in the new order.  As it stands, something like this...

```
procedure arrange_items(
  ITEM_CODES in CORE.T_STRINGARRAY,
  PARENT in VARCHAR2
) 
as
  V_SEQS T_NUMBERARRAY := T_NUMBERARRAY();
begin

  for i in 1..ITEM_CODES.count loop
    V_SEQS.extend();
    V_SEQS(i) := i; 
  end loop

  forall i in 1..ITEM_CODES.count
    update MENU_ITEMS
    set SEQ = V_SEQS(i)
    where ITEM_CODE = ITEM_CODES(i) and PARENT_CODE = PARENT;

end arrange_items
```

**PROBLEM**

1. When calling the procedure with `ITEM_CODES = ("APPLES", "BANANAS", "CHERRIES")`, I get a 'unique constraint violated' exception (...presumably because the first item's `SEQ` can't be set to 1 while there exists another row whose `SEQ` is also `1`)
2. I don't know how to handle items that weren't specified in the `ITEM_CODES` parameter, whose sequence is irrelevant (being disabled menu items and never displayed.) NB: Only the items to be re-arranged can be included in the `ITEM_CODES` array parameter; disabled items *not* requiring re-arranging can't be passed in.

Reading the Oracle docs seems to suggest a BULK COLLECT/UPDATE is needed to change all the records in one hit without violating the unique constraint (I had thought `FORALL` instead of `FOR LOOP` might do this) but I have extremely limited SQL knowledge and can't get the application right, nor can I see a way of taking into account the unspecified `ITEM_CODES` whose sequence might need changing just to avoid conflicting with the codes that *were* specified.

Is anyone able to suggest at least the correct approach I should investigate, if not a working solution?

Comment: I don't know why it got downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without changing your procedure unless you disable the constraints.

There seems to be nothing wrong with your code although you could have used simple update statements than `FORALL`. The problem is that when you are updating the column seq , a unique  entry already exists for the same `parent_code` and `seq` . It is only that you are reordering it while running your update statement. So , the constraint will be violated no matter how you change the order of update.

So, the solution I recommend you is to disable the constraint.If you don't know the constraint name, you need to look at `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` or `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS`  data dictionary view giving proper column names.Refer this link if you need.

[Constraint name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404046/getting-unique-constraint-column-names-from-oracle-database)

```
ALTER TABLE MENU_ITEMS DISABLE CONSTRAINT name_of_unique_constraint;
```

Then execute your procedure and make sure you don't have any duplicate `(SEQ,PARENT_CODE )`combination after update.

Then enable constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE MENU_ITEMS ENABLE CONSTRAINT name_of_unique_constraint;
```

and make sure it does not fail.

**EDIT:** : It seems the word **"can't"** I used at the top was taken as a challenge by others and alternate solutions were provided, which is much appreciated. I have slightly changed my first sentence to make it clear.

Comment: `There seems to be nothing wrong with your code although you could have used simple update statements than FORALL`- There is a problem. If we disable the constraint then in that case then the SEQ number will be duplicated with `Update` and i guess that is not somthing OP would need.

Comment: @XING : It is strange and remarkable how the sentences and phrases  nitpicked without considering what follows and what precedes  is taken out can mean something completely controversial. Our modern popular media has taken this method to another level to sell their news :)

Comment: There was nothing i nitpicked. I justed said if you disable the constraint then the result wil not the same as desired. It would cause duplicate on SEQ and that is something which OP doesnt want.

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak thanks so much. A bautifully explained answer. It would never have occurred to me I could suspend the constraint like that!!  I am confident I can write a procedure that precludes duplicates when it's re-enabled, but other than that risk is there anything "hacky" about changing a constraint on the fly, or is it a perfectly standard solution on occasion?

Comment: @Bumpy : It is perfectly normal, although I suggest  It would be better to have this activity performed offline when there are no active transactions on the database.One thing that comes to my mind although is If you have any `Foreign Key` that is referencing this `Unique Key` , you may need to disable them.I am unaware of the size and  scope of your database /table ,but it should not be much of an issue as you can check it in the test/dev environments.  Best of Luck.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly with `FORALL` Agreed with Kaushik: disable the constraint.

## solution without Disabling the constraint: add `Max(SEQ) +1` to every row, then do your thing:

```
create or replace procedure arrange_items(
  ITEM_CODES in T_STRINGARRAY,
  PARENT in VARCHAR2
) as
  V_SEQS T_NUMBERARRAY := T_NUMBERARRAY();
  i pls_integer;
  mx number;
begin
  -- calculat max:
  select max(seq) into mx from MENU_ITEMS;
  -- Add max(SEQ)
  update MENU_ITEMS
    set SEQ = SEQ + mx+1
  where PARENT_CODE = PARENT;
  -- then your stuff works 
  for i in 1..ITEM_CODES.count loop
    V_SEQS.extend();
    V_SEQS(i) := i; 
  end loop;
  forall i in 1..ITEM_CODES.count
    update MENU_ITEMS
    set SEQ = V_SEQS(i)
    where ITEM_CODE = ITEM_CODES(i) and PARENT_CODE = PARENT;
end arrange_items;
/
```

Comment: Do you know, that's almost the solution I was trying before I gave up except I chose an arbitrarily large number instead of Max. Unless I've misunderstood, you still need yet a *third* loop with a different increment, otherwise the next call to the procedure will probably conflict with any unused items from the previous call that remained incremented.  I only went off this approach because I found an answer about MS SQL that implied this wasn't a problem with some method I assumed to be the equivalent of FORALL. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Ah, actually I just noticed you're incrementing SEQ relative to itself each call.  I assigned absolute numbers over 3 loops... first seq=1,000+i for all items of parent, then 2,000+I for unselected, then 0+i for the selected list.  Not sure if I can think of a case  where incrementing might cause a duplicate violation, but is there an upper limit that continual increments are lkely to reach?

Comment: @Bumpy, in fact the solution update every record edited beforehand, because it is the same WHERE clause. Happy it helped.

Comment: Ok.I think I got you now.